# systemLayoutSizeFittingSize not returning size.. height is always 0

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, ios7, ios8

I have a custom Nib that I have set to utilize for `UITableView` Header. In the nib I have 3 labels, in which first two are changes its height dynamically. I can see their height in `UIView` being changed and its rendering fine, however I am trying to utilize `systemLayoutSizeFittingSize` to get the actual height of the custom `UIView` so the `UITableViewCell` doesn't overlap. However, every time I try to utilize `systemLayoutSizeFittingSize` to get the View's height, I keep getting 0. I have made this call in pretty much all the viewLoad's methods, and I have never seen its height being changed. Would anyone know what I might be missing? I am setting the Nib's constraints within the nib file.